# AWS RDS Postgres: How to diagnose CheckpointLag and potential slowups using AWS' Monitoring suite?

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-rds, aws

We are currently hosting a postgres RDS database and our team is noticing slowup in our querying service. I'm noticing a spike in the metric, `CheckpointLag` and I've been tasked in trying to find where this occurs specifically on the AWS side of things.

In monitoring detailed performance, we've seen that our queries are much below (`20%`) what our expected average active sessions (AAS) are said to reach. I also monitored the queries individually with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and the most extreme query is takes `0.5s` to compute. This leads me to believe there's something else taking too long.

After checking other potential metrics, CPU, BurstBalance, etc... all appear normal, there is one metric `CheckpointLag` which appears to have a spike under use and I can't seem to find documentation on. I can't seem to find what this means and the expected *acceptable* value we should expect with a `db.m4.xLarge`. With no, to low, usage -- it appears to be `~140 seconds`. Under normal, expected usage it jumps to `~400 seconds`.

I'm asking what this metric really means, if the values are of *expected* or *normal* values, and if there's any other ways I can see if my RDS instance is the cause of my slowup?

**EDIT:**

Checkpoint lag is defined as a metric here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html  with the description of `The amount of time since the most recent checkpoint`. It was fairly vague and hard to decipher the true meaning. For my metrics, it appears that its pulling from this already pre-defined metric, but if there's a way to dive deeper in how its querying the instance, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps it's something you could ask AWS support. "Checkpoint lag" isn't a term  commonly used when speaking about Postgres, as far as I know.

Comment: Right. At leat tell us how this "CheckpointLag" is defined and measured.

Comment: I'll ping AWS support, its a pre-defined metric, but I'm not seeing where its being pulled from. Edited post nonetheless.